# Airflow Scheduler fails with error `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb.OperationalError) (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')`

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, airflow, airflow-2.x

I'm using Airflow 2.5.1 and setting up Airflow scheduler (Using LocalExecutor) + webserver on Deb9 Instance.
MySQL DB is on another instance and I checked using PING and `airflow db check` that the connection to the MySQL server is successful. I had even run `airflow db init` from this instance and it was able to create all the tables successfully.

When I start the scheduler using `airflow scheduler` command, getting the following error:

airflow-scheduler.err log below:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb.OperationalError) (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
[2023-02-09 01:12:34 +0530] [15451] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 8793)
[2023-02-09 01:12:34 +0530] [15451] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2023-02-09 01:12:35 +0530] [15451] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 8793)
[2023-02-09 01:12:35 +0530] [15451] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2023-02-09 01:12:36 +0530] [15451] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 8793)
[2023-02-09 01:12:36 +0530] [15451] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2023-02-09 01:12:37 +0530] [15451] [ERROR] Can't connect to ('0.0.0.0', 8793)
```

airflow-scheduler.log below:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb.OperationalError) (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
2023-02-09 01:12:33,040 INFO - Shutting down LocalExecutor; waiting for running tasks to finish.  Signal again if you don't want to wait.
2023-02-09 01:12:34,066 INFO - Sending Signals.SIGTERM to group 15492. PIDs of all processes in the group: [15492]
2023-02-09 01:12:34,066 INFO - Sending the signal Signals.SIGTERM to group 15492
2023-02-09 01:12:34,158 INFO - Process psutil.Process(pid=15492, status='terminated', exitcode=0, started='01:12:32') (15492) terminated with exit code 0
2023-02-09 01:12:34,159 INFO - Exited execute loop
```

Any idea why is this happening?

**[Update]**

`Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 8793)` was because of some processes running from previous run. Have killed those processes. But I'm still getting `MySQL server has gone away` error.

airflow-scheduler.err log:

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/airflow_venv/bin/airflow", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/airflow/airflow_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/__main__.py", line 39, in main
    args.func(args)
  File "/home/airflow/airflow_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 52, in command
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/airflow_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 108, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/airflow_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/scheduler_command.py", line 68, in scheduler
    _run_scheduler_job(args=args)
  File "/home/airflow/airflow_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/scheduler_command.py", line 43, in _run_scheduler_job
    job.run()
  File "/home/airflow/airflow_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/jobs/base_job.py", line 258, in run
    self._execute()
  File "/home/airflow/airflow_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/jobs/scheduler_job.py", line 759, in _execute
    self._run_scheduler_loop()
  File "/home/airflow/airflow_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/jobs/scheduler_job.py", line 840, in _run_scheduler_loop
    self.adopt_or_reset_orphaned_tasks()
  File "/home/airflow/airflow_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 75, in wrapper
    return func(*args, session=session, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 119, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/home/airflow/airflow_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 36, in create_session
    session.commit()
  File "/home/airflow/airflow_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1451, in commit
    self._transaction.commit(_to_root=self.future)
  File "/home/airflow/airflow_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 836, in commit
    trans.commit()
  File "/home/airflow/airflow_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2459, in commit
    self._do_commit()
  File "/home/airflow/airflow_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2649, in _do_commit
    self._connection_commit_impl()
  File "/home/airflow/airflow_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2620, in _connection_commit_impl
    self.connection._commit_impl()
  File "/home/airflow/airflow_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1091, in _commit_impl
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(e, None, None, None, None)
  File "/home/airflow/airflow_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2125, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e
  File "/home/airflow/airflow_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 211, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/home/airflow/airflow_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1089, in _commit_impl
    self.engine.dialect.do_commit(self.connection)
  File "/home/airflow/airflow_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 686, in do_commit
    dbapi_connection.commit()
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb.OperationalError) (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

Answer (score 0):

When running the LocalExecutor, the scheduler also starts a process to serve log files, by default on port 8793. The error tells you you've already got something running on port 8793, therefore it can't start and returns an error. You've probably already got a scheduler running.

The port is configurable by `AIRFLOW__LOGGING__WORKER_LOG_SERVER_PORT`. For more information, see https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#worker-log-server-port.

Comment: Yes, that was because I had not killed these processes from the previous run. I did now, and the connection error is gone. But`MySQL server has gone away` error is still there.